# Icomoon issues with rails 4 on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, icons

I have a rails 4 app deployed on heroku. Inside my assets/stylesheets, i have a icomoon folder with its styles and icomoon fonts file. The icomoon is rendered in the pages during development mode but not when deployed to heroku. I have installed the gem 'rails_12factor' and set config.serve_static_assets = true. What is causing the icomoon to be not loaded during production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `asset-url` SASS helper?
There is also a `font-url` helper if you relocate your fonts to `assets/fonts`